# Which function I can use to send a simple text from the php server to android

Tags: php, android

If I have the following string variable in a `php` file:

```
$text = "Hello World";
```

Can I use `print(json_encode($text));` to send  the `$text` to the `void` function such as the following function in android?

```
void getString(String text) { // Do somethings on the text variable }
```

Comment: yes, but what will you do with the `getString(string)` function? print something or what?

Comment: could you be more precise on what you are doing ?

Comment: My question was only this :) Because I do not work with **JSON**  
I thought that I should use the **JSON** and I should learn **JSON** . As I understand the **print(json_encode(...));** is to send data in the client.

Comment: Excuse me. Also can I use the **echo  $text**  instead of the **print(json_encode($text));** to send the text to the android? I think it is possible, but I doubt.